# Use selenium click check box google form

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-forms

I want to use selenium chrome click check box in google form demo in this link

[Google form demo](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSee-3p39HAeLYchK1UMin_KPDB_E40GNkbYFS5u-sz0Pza_Rg/viewform?usp=sf_link)

This is my code:

```
var ElementMulti = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio"));

foreach (IWebElement element in ElementMulti)
{
    element.Click();
}
```

The code does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with selenium, And you haven't really said what the problem is, however have you tried `element.Invoke();` also when I had a look at the example, the classes name is `quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio exportOuterCircle`

Comment: My problem is, Selenium can't click radio button in google form. I already to make demo google form in this link https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSee-3p39HAeLYchK1UMin_KPDB_E40GNkbYFS5u-sz0Pza_Rg/viewform?usp=sf_link Only 1 radio button in this form. You can try

Comment: but this is radio button so you only clicked one item at a time.

Comment: Tried java equivalent of your code (taking the same classname) and works like a charm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");              
driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSee-3p39HAeLYchK1UMin_KPDB_E40GNkbYFS5u-sz0Pza_Rg/viewform");
Thread.sleep(2);

// Radio 1 select
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/content/div/label[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div")).click();
Thread.sleep(2);

// Radio 5 select
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/content/div/label[5]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div")).click();
Thread.sleep(2);

// Submit button clicked.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/content/span")).click();
Thread.sleep(2);

driver.close();
```

This is selenium java code. And it's working fine.

It opened the given link and then click on the first radio button the last radio button and then clicked on the submit button.

Comment: Sorry but I not enough reputation to up vote. @@ Please wait some day, I will get more reputation